# General question about Actuarial mathematics

Tags: statistics, actuarial-science

Basically, I am currently in my undergraduate degree with to a statistics major and this semester I took an intro course in Actuarial studies. I found this quite interesting as it seems like it uses most of the theoretical math that I have studies into application so I am considering doing a postgraduate degree in actuarial studies.

My question is, for anyone who has experience with stats and/or actuarial studies what are the best courses for me to do as a stats major that can help better my transition to advanced actuarial science. So far I have done the basics calculus 2, vector calculus, linear algebra, real analysis and will do probability and differential equations next semester.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Actuary" is defined differently in various countries. In all cases of which I'm aware Mathematics, Statistics, and Probability are integral parts of the required training. But Accounting, Tax Law, and other topics may also be included.

The first thing you need to do is to study the web sites of the actuarial societies in your country to find out what is covered on the actuarial exams. In the US and Canada, the usual procedure is to pass the first couple of exams (low administration fee) and then complete the rest (higher administration fees) while working for an actuarial firm or insurance company.

You should make sure that you are interested in all of the academic areas
required for the exams, and make an assessment of how much of each area
you already know. Then see which postbac programs just mention actuarial careers
among many possible ones for graduates and which programs are directly
targeted towards a career as an actuary.

Most actuaries work for insurance companies in the main offices, which tend to be concentrated in certain places. In the US many insurance companies have headquarters in New York City and Connecticut, a few in Illinois and Nebraska,
not so many in the far western states. A few actuaries work for consulting
firms, HMOs, and so on. One consideration might be whether actuarial
jobs are concentrated in places you would like to live.

All of the courses you list as having taken seem relevant. If your department
has a beginning course in actuarial science, it is reasonable to suppose
that there are advisers in the department who know your accomplishments
and how they can fit into a coherent plan of study to become and actuary.
After reading about the profession on society websites so you are familiar
with the field, you should see if you can get some advice from faculty who
know you and understand your plans.

Opinions from this or other social web sites may or may not be as well informed as they
seem to be.
And advice from people who know you may be much more useful.